# Hover up modal over another hover up modal in mobile UI

Tags: mobile-application, modal

Is it better to use a hover up modal over another hover up modal on mobile UI? In the current situation I want to open an information page when the user taps on a certain card, and that information page also can have some task (e.g update info etc.)

Why I thought to have hovers is to prevent opening multiple separate pages.

Please someone help me out to sort this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modals on top of modals is never optimal, especially in mobile - it's harder for users to dismiss and the user has to remember the task they came from and sometimes they need the information on the previous screen to complete their task.

A mobile pattern you could use is selecting the card and taking the user to another screen and allowing them to go back to the previously selected card or if you have to use the modal then make sure it can be easily dismissed with an "x" or a swipe down behavior.

There might be other patterns that you can use - check out the sites here:

- https://pttrns.com/
- https://www.mobile-patterns.com/

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction is this isn't the best method. It's very rare to see modal windows on top of modal windows. Can the top level information page be a page instead of a modal? Could the 2nd level modal be replaced by an expand or slide or multi-step task?

If you could clarify what you mean by task, information page and card that might help generate better insight/advice.